# Compare numbers without deleting them - Turing machines

Tags: compare, automata, turing-machines

Is there a way to compare two binary numbers with a Turing machine without deleting them in the process?

Comment: Does copying them to the end of the tape, comparing them by deleting the originals, using the copies to write the originals back and then deleting the copies, count as a solution to your problem? You'd have the same tape contents at the end of the computation as if you had compared the numbers without deleting.

Comment: Or compare-delete copies?

Comment: @Patrick87 i suppose that has to work. thank you.